# .htaccess not asking password

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK I have a website I am coding and it has a blog. I want to be able to post from anywhere so I have a page with a form that posts it. I don't want just anyone to post things. I set up a .htacces file with http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/ to password it. When I click on it goes to the error site of the hosting company(will change later). It should pop up and ask for a password but doesn't. I am using chrome and have already reset it. I have the htacces and htpasswd in the same file as the post file. Here is the website [sagethesite.comuv.com](http://sagethesite.comuv.com)

.htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
# username: admin; pass:admin12
admin:3/Iu.1Af.Qd0g
```

file hierarchy:
blog
< post
<<.htpasswd
<<.htaccess
<< postpage.php

Comment: go on...? What's the error page?

Comment: Go check it yourself, I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: I do not see any error message by the link. Also `AuthUserFile /.htpasswd` the path here is not with respect to the root of the website, but the path in the file system. I do not think that you have `.htpasswd` in the root of the partition.

Comment: What do you mean that the .htaccess and .htpasswd are in the same file as the post file??

Comment: remove the front slash of `/.htpasswd´, with the slash it would mean that the passwd file is in root

Comment: Removed the / still nothing. Sorry this is probably kinda stupid. Could someone explain what the language is and stuff like that.

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache httpd construct, with its own, rather extensive, documentation. A good start is [htaccess-guide](http://htaccess-guide.com), but the [full docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) are also packed with examples, advice, and information not always found elsewhere. The htaccess-guide covers password protection [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/password-protection)

Comment: http://blog.sagethesite.comuv.com/post/postpage.php asks me for credentials …

Comment: Thanks mike. Should I be checking if it is my pc then CBroe.

Comment: basic auth will store your creds will your browser is still open.
Test with different browser or clear browser cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the the AuthGroupFile statement.

Comment: Nope. Still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

**.htpasswd entry**

```
demouser:$apr1$KA.8IONB$PkmuR1hj4UwTLet4xhDPD1
```

[HTPASSWD GENERATOR](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

**.htaccess Entry**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Your Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```